# Hybris-Solid Concepts of hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone please tell me the solid concepts of hybris ? I have google it but could not find any exact answer .This is the question asked in Interview .

Answer (score 4):

[SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) is an acronym that refer to the 5 first principles of object-oriented design.

It's a generic concept that should be followed in hybris. However hybris follows the same principle so you don't have to  worry about an "hybris version" of SOLID.

It's briefly mentionned here (look for SRP) : [Code Review Check](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/hybrisALF/Code+Review+Checklist)

Answer (score 2):

SOLID stands for five principles used in OOP(Object Oriented Programming) when designing software so that the developed system will be easier to extend and maintain  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design).

Also it is independent of the Programming Language(it can be applied using different programming languages) and independent of the platform(which in this case is Hybris Platform),
and that is way in my opinion linking them(i.e Hybris-SOLID concepts) does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It means some "hybris concepts" you must know:

- Extension
- Addon
- Accelerator
- Cronjob
- backoffice
- cockpit
- workflow
- impex
- Flexiable Search
- DataHub
- hotfolder
- Jalo/JaloLayer
- YAAS(hybris as a service)
- ...

Please refer to Hybris wiki if you want to know more. https://wiki.hybris.com

Answer (score 1):

Basic or solid concept in **Hybris** refers to the core concept which includes below topics:

- item xml
- type system
- addon
- accelerator - B2B/B2C
- backoffice
- build framework
- ... + more

Copied: [Meaning of basic concepts in Hybris](https://www.queshub.com/meaning-of-basic-concepts-in-hybris-sap-cx)

Answer (score 0):

SOLID is acronym for 5 design principles. Here are few examples based on SAP Comemrce(hybris)

1. **Single Responsibility Principle** - Each extension performs a specific role
2. **Open/Closed Principle** - Classes in platform extension are open for extension but closed for midification.
3. **Liskov Substitution Principle** -
4. **Interface Segregation Principle**
5. **Dependency Inversion** - Bean injection using spring.xml and coding to interface instead of implementation.